# youtube analytics api cooperating channel demographic data

Tags: youtube-analytics-api

Got a question from my job. How to obtain the analytics demographic data of channels that are not owned by the service-account? Does youtube have for channel-owners or content-owners to share access to this data? We do not own the content or the channel but a partnership could be arranged. We do not intend to modify, write or alter any of the content.

Best Regards.